# How many agents are active characters?

Tags: uplink

**How many Uplink Agents are characters that perform interactive actions in the game world?**

Over the course of the game, some of your fellow Uplink agents will perform AI-driven actions and go about their own hacking in your world.  You sometimes come into conflict with them, as missions can be issued to track them down, or they may accept missions to hunt for you as well.

Are the **agents listed in the Top 10 Agents List** the **only ones** that are able to be interacted with, or are **some of the other nameless agents** off the bottom of the list also characters?

**What about the agent who is Agent #10 when the game starts?**  At the start of the game, you yourself are not on the Top 10 List, but eventually can be, thus bumping the previous #10 spot off the list.  Does this agent **continue to be a character** after they've been removed from the list?

Comment: I don't know about activity - but hacking Uplink Internal Service Machine allows you to get hacker list containing (more or less, it's been some time) 40 agent names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many other agents that you may not directly interact with but have some effect on the game world. If you look at your news feed you may see some agents get "caught" where Uplink is mentioned as an employer, but their name is not on the top 10 list.

As far as I know, the missions that require you to frame another agent are usually ones in the top 10 list.